# Does my device tamper with sound?

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I am using Clementine to output directly to ALSA (hw:0,0). Does that option has any resampling/converting in it? I need it as lossless as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plughw` device would automatically add resampling/converting, if needed.
The `hw` device goes directly to the kernel driver.

Comment: So the 'hw' device does direct digital output to sound card without any conversions?